# Docker keeps saying must be a superuser

Tags: docker, superuser

I have a docker image which runs `tomcat`. Whenever I deploy a detached container and login to the container using `docker exec`, I usually get logged in by default as root. However, whenever I try commands like `mount/umount`, the container shell keeps returning an error saying `must be superuser`

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try `sudo mount`?

Comment: did you tried with `docker exec -it --user root container_name sh`>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even as root, the set of things you can do inside a Docker container is limited.  There's some discussion of this under ["Runtime privilege and Linux capabilities" in the `docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).  Among the things you can't do in a container without additional configuration is **mount(8)** additional filesystems.

In general, though, it's not good Docker practice to `docker exec` into containers and start making changes.  You usually want to set things up so that you can run a single `docker run` (or `docker-compose up`) command, and everything is automatically configured for you.  This is especially important when you start looking at things like restart policies or clustered environments like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes: manually tweaking things after startup doesn't work well when you have multiple copies of a container, potentially on different hosts, that might restart on their own.

Docker has some built-in support for managing filesystems in the container and it's better to use that:

- If you're trying to `mount --bind` a host directory for things like publishing logs out, Docker has its own [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) system, so you can

  ```
  docker run -v $PWD/host/directory/path:/container/path ...
  ```
- If you're trying to mount a physical device for external storage, you can **mount**(8) it on the host and then bind-mount it into the container as above.
- Or, you can manually configure a Docker [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to mount a physical device.  The [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) command takes extended options that let you manually specify most of the mount options, so you can

  ```
  docker volume create disk --driver local --opt device=/dev/sdX
  docker run -v disk:/container/path ...
  ```
- If you need to unmount a volume, stop the container, delete it, and re-run it with one fewer `-v` option.  (Stopping and recreating containers for config changes like this is extremely routine.)